# Code not functioning with larger lists

Tags: python, math, primes

I am coding for a problem on project euler. Problem 50 https://projecteuler.net/problem=50

The problem is my code works fine with small lists, specifically a list of primes under a few thousand, however, it fails to work with a list of primes under 1 million (with is around the 80000th prime) which is an issue in getting the answer.

There are two main problems:

1. It is horrendously slow with larger lists such roughly greater than 20000  (10 - 20mins)
2. It does not produce the correct answer

Even if the logic is correct and finishes running the answer is incorrect, is this a memory issue? I would like to know why my code only works with smaller data and how to improve my efficiency

Also, if I am asking a bad question let me know.

```
def primes(n):

   sieve = [True] * n
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5) + 1, 2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i * i :: 2 * i] = [False] * int((n - i * i - 1)/(2 * i) + 1)
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3, n, 2) if sieve[i]]

primes = primes(1000)
start = 0
answer = 0
x = 0
count = y = 2

while len(primes[x:y - 1]) < len(primes):
    summed = sum(primes[x:y])
    length = len(primes[x:y])
    if summed in primes and length > start:
        start = length
        answer = summed
    x += 1
    y += 1
    if y - 1 == len(primes):
        count += 1
        x = 0
        y = count

print(start)
print(answer)
```

Comment: `len(primes[x:y - 1])`. We know that `len(..)` will be `y-1-x`. Why do you actually take a sublist (this is an *O(n)* operation).

Comment: Similar, instead of `sum(primes[x:y])`, you could just subtract `primes[x-1]` from the previous sum and add `primes[y-1]`

Comment: Also, all primes are odd, so `count` has to be an odd number, or else the sum will be even and thus not a prime.

Comment: @tobias_k: That last statement need not be true if the consecutive primes start with 2. Of course, that is quick and easy to check.

Comment: @tobias_k could you explain why that works for me? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, there are a few unneccessary linear complexities in your code, e.g. for determining the number of elements in the current sum, or whether the number is in the list of primes. If you eliminate those, your algorithm becomes much faster.

```
p_set = set(primes)  # use a set for lookup
summed = None
while y - 1 - x < len(primes):
    # instead of getting the sublist and the sum, just update the last sum
    summed = sum(primes[x:y]) if summed is None else summed - primes[x-1] + primes[y-1]
    length = y - x  # no need for creating the sublist
    if summed in p_set and length > start:  # lookup in set
        start = length
        answer = summed
        print(start, answer)
    x += 1
    y += 1
    if y - 1 == len(primes):
        count += 1
        x = 0
        y = count
        summed = None  # reset sum
```

But depending on your computer this might still take more than a minute. This is because you first test all the sums of two primes, then all the sums of three primes, etc., by shifting both `x` and `y` before increasing the difference between the two.

If, instead, you turn this around, and first look at sums of many small primes, instead of sums of a few large primes, you will quickly find the result -- starting at the third prime!

```
max_ = res = 0
for i in range(len(primes)):
    sum_ = primes[i]
    for k in range(i+1, len(primes)):
        sum_ += primes[k]
        if sum_ in p_set and k - (i - 1) > max_:
            max_, res = k - (i - 1), sum_
            print(max_, res, i, k)
        if sum_ > MAX:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

I took another approach

I checked from each elements in the list of primes if there is a consecutive series, longer than the longest series found until then for which the sum is a prime

## generate the primes

```
import itertools
def primes(n):
    found_primes = [True] * (n + 1)
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        if found_primes[i]:
            yield i
            for j in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x * i <= n, itertools.count(1)):
                found_primes[j * i] = False
```

## Find a longer consecutive sum

```
def find_longer_consecutive_sums(elements):
    n = len(elements)
    elements_set = set(elements)
    max_elements = 1
    max_prime = elements[-1]
    for i in range(len(elements) - 1):
        if sum(elements[i: i + max_elements]) > max_prime:
            return
        for j, k in enumerate(itertools.islice(itertools.accumulate(elements[i:]), max_elements, len(elements)), max_elements + 1):
            if k in elements_set:
                max_elements = j
                yield i, j, k
```

- I used a set to check whether it was in because sets have fixed time search
- I stopped the iteration if there was not a possibility of a longer set which did not exceed the largest looked for prime
- I used some itertools magic with `enumerate`, `accumulate` and `islice` to:

  - look for an ever longer series: (`itertools.islice(x, max_elements, len(elements))`
  - in the sums starting at a particular place in the list of primes: `itertools.accumulate(elements[i:])`

## Tying it together

```
primes_list = list(primes(1000000))
results_longer = {}
for i, j, k in find_longer_consecutive_sums(primes_list):
    selected_primes = primes_list[i:i+j]
    print(i, j, k, sum(selected_primes), selected_primes)
    results_longer[(j, i, k)] = selected_primes
```

returns in slightly over a second:

```
0 2 5 5 [2, 3]
0 4 17 17 [2, 3, 5, 7]
0 6 41 41 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
0 12 197 197 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, ...
0 14 281 281 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, ...
0 60 7699 7699 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31...
0 64 8893 8893 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31...
0 96 22039 22039 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, ...
0 100 24133 24133 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,...
0 102 25237 25237 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,...
0 108 28697 28697 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,...
0 114 32353 32353 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,...
0 122 37561 37561 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,...
0 124 38921 38921 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,...
0 130 43201 43201 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,...
0 132 44683 44683 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,...
0 146 55837 55837 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,...
0 152 61027 61027 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,...
0 158 66463 66463 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,...
0 162 70241 70241 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,...
0 178 86453 86453 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,...
0 192 102001 102001 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 198 109147 109147 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 204 116533 116533 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 206 119069 119069 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 208 121631 121631 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 214 129419 129419 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 216 132059 132059 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 296 263171 263171 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 308 287137 287137 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 326 325019 325019 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 328 329401 329401 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 330 333821 333821 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 332 338279 338279 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 334 342761 342761 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 342 360979 360979 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 350 379667 379667 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 356 393961 393961 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 358 398771 398771 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 426 581921 581921 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 446 642869 642869 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 458 681257 681257 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 460 687767 687767 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 464 700897 700897 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 480 754573 754573 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 484 768373 768373 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 488 782263 782263 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 512 868151 868151 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 530 935507 935507 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
0 536 958577 958577 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 2...
2 537 970219 970219 [5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31,...
2 539 978037 978037 [5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31,...
3 543 997651 997651 [7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37...
```